# Can' update a WMS-source with changed params (updating cql-filter) in OL3 / Geoserver

Tags: wms, openlayers

I'm updating a WMS-Layer in a OL3-Map.

I tried to reload the wms-layer with updated clq_filter-params.

Can anyone correct my code or give me a working example?

```
// initialize filtervariable to show all states
var filterstring = "PERSONS>1";

// WMS Layer with cql-filter var filterstring
    var layers = [
            new ol.layer.Image({extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
            source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS':'topp:states','cql_filter': filterstring},
            serverType: 'geoserver'})}                  
        )
    ];

// OL Karte mit WMS
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
    center: [-10997148, 4569099],
    zoom: 4
    })
});

// get Filtervalue from form and replace clq-filter in ol.layer.tile params  
document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", func1);
    function func1(){
        var a=document.getElementById("zahl").value;
        var filterstring = "PERSONS>" + a;
    layer[ol.layer.Image].getSource().updateParams({params});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but I'm pretty sure that:

```
var filterstring = "PERSONS>" + a;
```

should be

```
filterstring = "PERSONS>" + a;
```

otherwise the global filterString is hidden by the local one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example.

```
function createparams() {MinPrice, MaxPrice, MinArea, MaxArea}
var MinPrice = document.getElementById('MinPrice').value;
var MaxPrice = document.getElementById('MaxPrice').value;
var MinArea = document.getElementById('MinArea').value;
var MaxArea = document.getElementById('MaxArea').value;
var cql = "'(price Between " +MinPrice.toString()+ ' AND '+ MaxPrice.toString()+ ') AND (area Between '+MinArea.toString()+ ' AND '+ MaxArea.toString()+ ")'";
```